# How to add secure registry to docker configuration

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use `registry.centos.org` with docker.

I've tried the add the below to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as, intuitively this would seem like the obvious place to add it, and the logical variable name.

```
{
  "insecure-registries": ["172.30.0.0/16"],
  "secure-registries": ["registry.centos.org"]
}
```

I then tried to restart the docker service, but it failed to restart.

Google provides lots of links on how to setup a secure registry, but I couldnt find any info on how to add new secure registries to docker configuration.

Likewise the website for registry.centos.org also doesnt provide any info on how to do this.

Comment: Have you attempted to pull an image from the registry directly, and if so, what errors did you encounter? You should be pulling and running images with the registry name prefixed to the image name if they are not on the docker hub.

Comment: Yes, I have. And running `docker pull registry.centos.org/...` works without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to pull the image, then there's nothing further to do. All external registries by default are secure, which means docker will require a TLS connection and valid certificate for the registry server. The insecure registry section is to allow exceptions to this rule.

There is also the option to override the CA certificate for a registry server, which is useful if you have a self hosted registry server, with TLS, but an unknown CA. For this, you would place the CA certificate, and any intermediate certificates, in `/etc/docker/certs.d/${hostname}:${port}/ca.crt` e.g. `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.example.com:5000/ca.crt`.